# Most efficient way to serve a single file for entire server block?

Tags: nginx, file-server

I have a subdomain for which only 1 single file will ever be served for any and all purposes.

Sample Reference:

```
server{
    listen          80;
    server_name     one.example.com;
    return          200 'hello';
}
```

Instead of a string, what would be the most efficient/otherwise best way to server an .html file?
Or is this:

```
server{
    listen          80;
    server_name     one.example.com;
    location * {
        root /home/;
        try_files /one.html /one.html;
    }
}
```

as simple as it gets?

Comment: Does your solution work, cause if so, then I think you have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make it much more efficient, but I have a couple of minor tweaks:

- "location /" rather than "location *" could be marginally more efficient, if it suits your needs
- your try_files doesn't need to list the same file twice
- your OS will likely cache the file, but you could make a ram disk - on Centos I use /dev/shm
- you could put CloudFlare or another CDN in front of it, so it's served from a global network of servers. If you use CF you would need to configure it to "cache everything" mode - html is not cached by default.

Comment: `try_files` requires a minimum of two arguments.